# How do I create a system restore point using a batch file?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, restore

Hi I am trying to make a batch file that can create a system restore point. I have looked on Google and all I can find is vbs scripts and I need it to be a batch file can anyone helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need something like this http://powercutin.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Create-Manual-System-Restore-Point-in-Windows-7-Script